# PHP & MySQL's STR_TO_DATE

Tags: php, mysql, sql-date-functions

I'm trying convert a date that is stored in a mysql datebase as a VARCHAR (format example: 12/29/2012) and then I want to ORDER BY it so that the older dates are on top followed by fore current dates.

```
Eg: 
11-01-2012
11-05-2012
12-25-2012
...
```

Here is what I have so far, (PLEASE HELP!! THANKS)

```
<?php
        $listsql = "SELECT contact.id, CONCAT(lastname,', ',firstname) AS fullname, lastname, firstname,
                    STR_TO_DATE(daDATE,'%m-%d-%Y'), line1, line2, city, state, zip, phone1, phone2, country, whoAdded
                    FROM ". TABLE_CONTACT ." AS contact
                    LEFT JOIN ". TABLE_ADDRESS. " AS address ON contact.id=address.id AND contact.primaryAddType=address.type
                    LEFT JOIN ". TABLE_EMAIL ." AS email ON contact.id=email.id AND contact.primaryAddType=email.type
                    WHERE contact.hidden != 1
                    ORDER BY email.daDATE";
?>
```

Comment: It is _very highly recommended_ to change the column's data type to a proper DATETIME and store real date values there.

Comment: Your `STR_TO_DATE()` above is `%m-%d-%Y`, but your example data is `%m/%d/%Y`.

Comment: If it were stored properly as a date in SQL then you could use SQL's ORDER BY clause

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski sorry it's stored using %m-%d-%Y

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski understand that but there has to be a way just to convert it on the fly and then use ORDER BY, no ?

Comment: @compcobalt It is certainly possible, but is terribly inefficient. It is such a bad idea that many are probably not going to take the time to try to make your approach work, as it is really just the wrong approach to take.

Comment: @MikeBrant got it... will change it to DATETIME data type... Thanks.

Comment: @compcobalt Good deal.  I have update my answer below with suggestion on how to update your table with new date fields.

Comment: @MikeBrant Yes I noticed that has really helped me out ALOT!!! THANKS so much for that update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments have indicated to you.  You REALLY should change the field type to a `date` or `datetime` (if you need H-M-S info).  While you can certainly do string manipulation on a date value in a text type field, you will not have any way to use an index to make filtering/sorting/grouping that you may want to do on that field efficient.

If you need help converting I might suggest this approach. Add a new date or datetime column. Make sure to add an index on this column since you will be using it for ordering.

Then run this query:

```
UPDATE table SET new_date_column = STR_TO_DATE(old_date_column, '%m-%d-%Y');
```

Then delete the old column from the table.

Answer (score 0):

you can order it on the fly using `SUBSTR()` and `INSTR()` to identify each part of the date, then order by the year, then month then day part.  Like everyone else said, it is better to either store it as a `date` or unixtime integer.  You can change it to `yyyy-mm-dd` and the orderby would work natively.

if you insist on the most difficult way possible it would be something like (year, month, day):

```
ORDER BY SUBSTR(email.daDATE,INSTR(email.daDATE,'-',2)+1) DESC,
         SUBSTR(email.daDATE,INSTR(email.daDATE,'-',1)+1,INSTR(email.daDATE,'-',2)-1) DESC,
         SUBSTR(email.daDATE,0,INSTR(email.daDATE,'-')-1) DESC
```

or something like that.  this was on the fly off the top of my head, but I think it is accurate.  Look up the functions for their usage if it doesnt work as intended.

Comment: Disagree with comment about using UNIXTIME integer to represent date data.  This is problematic for a number of reasons including readability of the data in the database, lack of ability to easily group or filter by date while still using an index, and for the case of a datefield (not datetime) causes a resolution problem in that you have to convert unixtime to nearest day before insert of data. In most cases you are going to be better of representing date/time data in an SQL database using the native date/time field types.

Comment: I agree with the resolution issue, I was just taking it from the question asked where he had only month day and year.  I personally use datetime or unixtime integer (for marginally faster math if required), but that was not the question I was answering.  The user wanted a convoluted technique for performing a task that should not be performed, I had a few extra minutes so decided to tell him of an obscure (absurd) way to accomplish it.